# Insert into a table based on the foreign keys from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have one table containing multiple foreign keys. When I insert values into other tables, this table needs to show the inserted foreign keys. Also, ContactDate should be the current date.

When I try to execute the following, I only have inserted ContactDetails, and the rest are all NULL.

```
EXEC usp_addQuickContacts 'minnie.mouse@disney.com','John 
Lasseter','Minnie getting Homework Support from John','Homework
Support'
```

I have also tried inserting them one by one instead of the inner join, but the result doesn't line up in the same row.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE usp_addQuickContacts
(
    @StudentEmail VARCHAR(100),
    @EmployeeName NVARCHAR(100),
    @ContactDetails NVARCHAR(200),
    @ContactType NVARCHAR(100)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    
    IF @contactDetails NOT IN (SELECT ContactDetails FROM StudentContacts)
        INSERT INTO StudentContacts(ContactDetails)
        VALUES (@contactDetails )

    IF @StudentEmail NOT IN (SELECT Email From StudentInformation)
        INSERT INTO StudentInformation(Email)
        VALUES (@StudentEmail )

    IF @contactType NOT IN (SELECT ContactType FROM ContactType) 
        INSERT INTO ContactType (ContactType)
        VALUES (@contactType)

    IF @EmployeeName NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeName FROM Employees)
        INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeName)
        VALUES (@EmployeeName )


    INSERT INTO StudentContacts(StudentID, EmployeeID, ContactDetails, ContactDate, ContactTypeID)
    SELECT si.StudentID, e.EmployeeID, sc.ContactDetails, sc.ContactDate,ct.ContactTypeID 
    FROM StudentContacts sc
    INNER JOIN StudentInformation si ON sc.StudentID = si.StudentID 
    INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.EmployeeID = sc.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN ContactType ct ON ct.ContactTypeID = sc.ContactTypeID
    INNER JOIN StudentContacts scs ON scs.ContactDate = sc.ContactDate
    WHERE (ct.ContactType= @ContactType) AND (si.Email = @StudentEmail) AND (e.EmployeeNAME = @EmployeeName ) AND (sc.ContactDetails = @contactDetails) AND (sc.ContactDate = GETDATE())

END
```

Comment: Debug it... take the contents of the SP and test it one statement at a time...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your code that there would may be problem in below part

> **(sc.ContactDate = GETDATE())**

Casting is not a good Option in where condition but you can try with as **(Cast(sc.ContactDate as Date) = Cast(GETDATE()) as Date)**